# Hiding a third party API key using Server Proxy

Tags: javascript, api, client-side-scripting

I need to use a third party API call in my client side JS and I know one way is to use a server proxy(for eg. www.myserver.com/getdata/) which can call the API and return the result to the front end. My question is even if I use a server proxy, won't someone else be able to make use of my third party API key indirectly by calling my server proxy instead of directly calling the Third party.

Comment: Yes, unless your proxy requires some sort of user authentication/existing login session.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the title is misleading, so i will try to answer the question stated in the body.
Yes and no: They can make use of the third party API key indirectly, but you retain full control over what data they can see. You also can validate user input before it is handed to the third party. Imagine a payment API: Do you really want to have the user have control over the amount of money you want to charge them?

In other words: If the API key of the third party is supposed to be kept secret then it probably is not a good idea to have it on the client.

Comment: Sorry about that, will change the title. So to just clarify, I only send data that is required from my server to client and this makes using the API key indirectly less useful for others. Am I right? They can still call the API indirectly but will get only values I send back.

Comment: Yes, especially because they only can use the end-points you provide and cannot arbitrarily access data with the same key.. But it really depends on the API on the other end. If it already is a publicly available API then there may not really be a need for a server between the client the third party api.

Comment: I'm getting charged per api call so I'll have to resort to using a server proxy. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah. That would be a good idea then. You may want to accept this answer so that it is marked as an answered question

Comment: Done. Thanks again!